# Leaks in Testing in instrumenst(Leaks-xcode) when pushing View controller from collectionView didSelectItemAt::

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I have a main view controller contains a collectionView , the mainViewController is the dataSource. when I push a view controller from  didSelectItemAt: while the second view controller in a local variable

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let monthVController = monthViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(monthVController, animated: true)

}
```

if 'animated' set to false the leaks disappears , and if the monthVController in a global variable it's also fine . If testing with xcode-instruments(Leaks-debug/relesa) shows leaks , is that true ?, I don't see any reason to leaks  .